# Tastypie alternative xml parser working with pypy

Tags: django, lxml, pypy, tastypie

So I want to run my django-tastypie based API on pypy. The problem is, tastypie uses lxml as xml serialiser and it's not compatible with pypy.

I'm looking for any help with switching from lxml to other xml serialiser that can be used with pypy.

Comment: lxml does work with PyPy.  You need to explain what error you got (including the PyPy version), and/or someone else than me needs to explain here which versions of lxml work with which versions of PyPy, which I don't really kwow.  I know that the future path is `https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml` branch "cffi" (which requires a PyPy trunk; PyPy 2.0.2 is too old already).

Comment: @ArminRigo - so you say lxml works with pypy out of box? If I make virtualenv with pypy as the inteprpreter and issue `pip install lxml` everything will go fine?

Comment: I said I don't know.  It seems that `pip install lxml` works indeed, but I can't test it any more.

Comment: `pip install lxml` will install the official version.
For PyPy you need to explicitly install the lxml-cffi port. For me this command worked:

    `pip install "git+git://github.com/amauryfa/lxml/@cffi-0.1a1#egg=lxml"`

This compiles from source though. You will need the development files of the libxml libraries (on Debian/Ubuntu: the `libxml2-dev` package)

Answer (score 2):

LXML was just ported to PyPy.

You need PyPy nightlies (link at the top of [this page](http://pypy.org/download.html)), then you can install it from [Amaury's repository](https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml/commits/cffi):

```
pip install [--user] git+https://github.com/amauryfa/lxml@cffi
```